Same button press different action pyautogui
I want to create python script that can send different link every time I press same button (Enter for example) so that it looks something like this:
First Enter press: google. com/#1Second Enter press: google. com/#2Third Enter press: google. com/#3and so on...I have tried to make it using python and pyautogui with no luck.
This is my current progress, but it only prints google .com/#1 and not #2, #3...
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time

linkext = ['#1','#2','#3']

for i in range(len(linkext)):
    link = 'https://google.com/'+linkext[i]
    
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
                    print(link)
                    pyautogui.typewrite(link)
                    time.sleep(0.25)

                
                    continue


i think that your while loop should remain on top, leaving different blocks handle your different events
to manage your link list you can use a generator and the next function
linktext = (f'example.com/#{i}' for i in range(1, 4))

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
        try:
            print(next(linktext))
        except StopIteration:
            break

